# "Failed to init OpenALSoundController" Monogame

Tags: monogame, openal

how to fix Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.NoAudioHardwareException: "Failed to init OpenALSoundController" and Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.NoAudioHardwareException: "Failed to init OpenALSoundController", TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MonoGame.OpenAL.AL' threw an exception? I try reinstall OpenAL, but nothing has changed.

Monogame version 3.8.0

Xna version 4.0

OpenAL version 3.05

Comment: open AL has nothing to do with XNA.

Comment: Can you show the line of code where this exception is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem on Android. I updated to the latest developer build of MonoGame and that sorted out the issue. Also, to prevent the initial crash I used try{} catch{} on each of my sound file imports to prevent the game from crashing.